# python sintaxError: invalid sintax , else:

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I get this invalid syntax error:

```
    File "./data_3.0.1.py", line 148
    else:    
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I try to run this function:

```
    def funzione_aggiornamento_prezzi(titolo):
    pprint ("titolo " + titolo)

#parametri per scaricare lo storico dei prezzi

    params = {'item': titolo, 
              'frequency': 'TBT',
              'dataDa':x_giorni_fa()} 

    try:
         r = requests.get(myurl, params=params)
    except:
         pprint("Si e' verificato un errore")
    else:
        pprint(r.status_code)
        pprint(r.url)        
        new_list = crea_lista(r)           


#codice per scrivere su di un csv da una lista
    nomen = "%s.TBT.csv" % (titolo)
    csvfile = open(nomen, 'a')    
    reportwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
#codice per scrivere su di un csv


# controllo del numero di rows nel file
    with open(nomen,"r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
        data = list(reader)
        row_count = len(data)

    if row_count == 0:
        for i in new_list:
            da_appendere = new_list[i+1]
            reportwriter.writerow(da_appendere)
    csvfile.close() 
#here I get the error   
    else:    
        with open(nomen, 'rb') as f:
        last_timestamp = f.readlines()[-1].split(",")[0]

#codice per aggiungere al csv solo i nuovi dati

        found_it = 0
        for i in new_list:
            if i == last_timestamp:
                found_it = 1
            if found_it == 1:
                da_appendere = new_list[i+1]
                reportwriter.writerow(da_appendere)
        csvfile.close()     


for i in lista_indici:
        funzione_aggiornamento_prezzi(i)
```

I don't understand what is the problem... Maybe is something very easy but.. I don't really see it!!
Basically what I want to do is say to python if the csv file you're opening is empty simply attach the new list otherwise attach only the elements from the new list that are not already in the csv file you just opened

Thanks

Comment: fix your indention in `try` and `except`

Comment: To be more specific: remove the extra space before each line in `try` and `except`.

Comment: The indentation of the line before the `else` is wrong as well (and in further lines, e.g. the first one).  Indentation is signifcant in Python, and wrong indentation is a syntax error in some cases (in other cases, it leads to wrong behaviour).

Comment: @zondo While the indentation of these lines is inconsistent, it's not technically wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The line `csvfile.close()` is outdented to be level with the `if` above it so terminates that if - so you have an `else:` when you are not in an `if`.  You also need to fix the indentation of the line after the `with`